# Export to image not showing fill map QGIS

Tags: qgis, resolution

When I go to export the map as an image, and then view the file it only displays a small portion of the map. I have been going into the printing business trying to get the resolution right and have tried to use previously saved templates which all exported to display the correct size. I know its a setting I have recently changed but can't find it or work out how to correct this output issue. Trying to export at 250dpi. I can see the window is too small in the layout screen.

[image: screengrab]